# @Watch('$router') is not fired and throws exception

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm diving deeper into Vue + Typescript. It was fine until I faced an issue with router.

My app structure is:

1. AppComponent (Root)
2. HomeComponent (is placed inside of router-view)
3. RequestsComponent (contains table with 10 requests. Each request is represented by #4)
4. RequestsRowComponent

RequestsComponent contains a paging control, so user is able to click buttons and route will change to /page/1, /page/2, /page/...

I have already tried to use inner routes, changing component that catches route change and everything like that.

Found some info that component can be already destroyed, but it's weird because I use this @Watch in different components. E.g. root AppComponent should not be destroyed at all.

I use VS2019.

Route configuration:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/', redirect: async (to: Route) => {
            await RedirectToLanguage();
        }
    },
    { path: '/:lang', redirect: '/:lang/page/1' },
    { path: '/:lang/page/:page', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
];
```

...

Requests.ts

```
    @Watch('$route')
    onPageChanged() {
        this.page = Number(this.$route.params['page']);
        this.refreshRequestList();
    }
```

I expect @Watch('$route') directive catches the route change in RequestsComponent and AppComponent. In reality code doesn't reach the @Watch method (or not always does that, during some fixes the breakpoint was hit, but not in 100%). Also I get an error in console:

Error in callback for watcher "$route": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

found in

--->  at \ClientApp\components\requestRow\requestRow.vue.html

at 
\ClientApp\components\requests\requests.vue.html

at 
ClientApp\components\home\home.vue.html

at 
ClientApp\components\app\app.vue.html

I believe cb is "callback", I'm not sure how a method can be undefined. Also it's strange that requestRow is in log.

I'm facing it for quite a long time so any help is highly appreciated. Could someone explain how to debug this issue and what can be a root cause? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all of those routes resolve to the same component. Here are two options:

```
@Watch('$route.params.page') onPageChanged() { ... }
```

Alternatively:

```
<router-view :key="$route.name + ($route.params.page || '')">
```

Which will force the route to update completely because the dynamic page property has changed.

Comment: The first option doesn't work, that's the issue. So I fixed it by separating dynamic content to a separate component with :key=$route.. Thanks for assistance.